# when checkbox is checked, change background color of div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, checkbox

What I'm trying to do is when the checkbox is checked, change the background color of the div, and when it's unchecked, remove the background color. How can I do this using jquery?

```
<div class="checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" class ="checkbox-border" id="personal-info-checkbox">
      <label for="personal-info-checkbox"> Mark as reviewed and acknowledged
      </label>
 </div>
```

using parent selector and .removeclass I do not know how to select my div and turn the color off and on using jquery.

Comment: What have you tried, in order to solve this yourself? Where's your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code? What went wrong - and in what way - with that code, were there any errors reported?

Comment: To give you a direction to start looking at, you need to set an event listener on your checkbox and, since using jQuery, you can use the `toggleClass()` method on your container element: https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 5):

You don't need jQuery for this
You can do this  only with css.

```
    .checkbox-container:has(input:checked) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

`:has` pseudo class is supported in chromium, safari.
For firefox, need to enable flag.
know more at mdn :[:has pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Comment: @Adamb this is not a good solution. The `:has` pseudo class has [very limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/css-has). So unless you only want to support ~1% of browser users, don't use it just yet.

Comment: @spectric all major supported except firefox. According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) report, 82.92% user's browser supported. In firefox, thisfeature behind **layout.css.has-selector.enabled**

Answer (score 1):

Add a `change` event listener to the `input` that sets its closest parent `div`'s background color based on whether it is checked:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', this.checked ? 'green' : 'white')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" class ="checkbox-border" id="personal-info-checkbox">
      <label for="personal-info-checkbox"> Mark as reviewed and acknowledged
      </label>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can do this

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click( () => {
    $("div").toggleClass("background");
  })
});
```

```css
.background {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:4em;">
Change colors<input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this:

1. CSS (with limited, as of writing, browser support),
2. jQuery (among other libraries), and
3. native JavaScript.

The below example has explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// using jQuery, we select the relevant element via its class, and use the on()
// method to bind the anonymous function as the event-handler for the 'change'
// event:
$('.checkbox-container.with-jQuery').on('change', function(){
  // here we find the <input> element descendant with find(), and then use the
  // is() method to test that element to see if it matches the :checked pseudo-
  // class; this returns a Boolean true/false which is cached in the 'checked'
  // variable:
    let checked = $(this).find('input').is(':checked');
  
  // here we use toggleClass() to toggle the 'checked' class-name on the element,
  // and use the 'checked' variable to ascertain whether the class should be
  // added/retained (if the Boolean is true) or removed/not-added (if the Boolean
  // is false):
    $(this).toggleClass('checked', checked);
});


// using JavaScript we use document.querySelector to retrieve the element
// with the listed classes; and use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the
// anonymous Arrow function as the event-handler for the 'change' event:
document.querySelector('.with-JavaScript.checkbox-container').addEventListener('change',(evt)=>{
  // we cache a reference to the current element (the <div>):
    let current = evt.currentTarget,
      // we find the <input> descendant, and access its checked property to
      // obtain a Boolean true (if checked) or false (if not-checked) and
      // store that Boolean in the 'checked' variable:
        checked = current.querySelector('input').checked;
  // here we use Element.classList.add() to add the 'active' class-name,
  // with the checked variable to determine if it should be added/retained
  // (if true) or removed/not-added (if false):
    current.classList.add('active', checked);
});
```

```css
:root {
  --checkedColor: lime;
}

/* here we select the element via classes, and use :has()
   to check if it has a descendant element which matches
   the enclosed selector: */
.with-CSS.checkbox-container:has(input:checked) {
  /* if so, we set the --checkedColor custom property
     as the background-color of the element: */
  background-color: var(--checkedColor);
}

.with-jQuery.checkbox-container.checked {
  background-color: var(--checkedColor);
}

.with-JavaScript.checkbox-container.active {
  background-color: var(--checkedColor);
}
```

```html
<!-- each wrapper <div> has a 'with-...' class applied in order to identify which
     approach is being taken: -->
<div class="checkbox-container with-CSS">
  <!-- an id must be unique, to that end - because there are three checkboxes in
       this example - the id has been modified, as has the corresponding <label>
       element's 'for' attribute: -->
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-border" id="personal-info-checkbox1">
  <label for="personal-info-checkbox1"> Mark as reviewed and acknowledged
  </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox-container with-jQuery">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-border" id="personal-info-checkbox2">
  <label for="personal-info-checkbox2"> Mark as reviewed and acknowledged
  </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox-container with-JavaScript">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-border" id="personal-info-checkbox3">
  <label for="personal-info-checkbox3"> Mark as reviewed and acknowledged
  </label>
</div>
```

References:

- Browser compatibility:

  - [`:has()`](https://caniuse.com/css-has).
- CSS:

  - [CSS Custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
  - [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).
  - [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).
  - [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- jQuery@

  - [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is).
  - [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on).
  - [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this I hope this will help you**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#personal-info-checkbox").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().addClass("color-blue");
    }else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("color-blue");
    }
  });
});
</script>
<style>
 .checkbox-container
 {
     padding:20px;
 }
 .color-blue {
     background-color:blue;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" class ="checkbox-border" id="personal-info-checkbox">
      <label for="personal-info-checkbox"> Mark as reviewed and acknowledged
      </label>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```